# knockout binding mvc not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, telerik, grid

I experimenting something with mvc and knockout.js but maybe a have binding problem.

My viewmodel is:

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
var currencyVm = function () {

var self = this;

var validationOptions = { insertMessages: true, decorateElement: true, errorElementClass: 'errorFill' };
ko.validation.init(validationOptions);

//ViewModel
self.ID = ko.observable(0);
self.Id_Region = ko.observable("");
self.Description = ko.observable("");
self.Symbol = ko.observable("");
self.PayPalCode = ko.observable("");
self.IFSCode = ko.observable("");


self.isGridVisible = ko.observable(true);
self.isEditVisible = ko.observable(false);
self.isAddVisible = ko.observable(false);


//Objects ---------------------------------------------
self.Currency = ko.observable();
self.Currencys = ko.observableArray([]);

//Methods ---------------------------------------------

//Edit
self.editCurrency = function (dataItem) {

    self.isGridVisible(false);
    self.isEditVisible(true);

    self.ID = ko.observable(dataItem.ID);
    self.Id_Region = ko.observable(dataItem.Id_Region);
    self.Description = ko.observable(dataItem.Description);
    self.Symbol = ko.observable(dataItem.Symbol);
    self.PayPalCode = ko.observable(dataItem.PayPalCode);
    self.IFSCode = ko.observable(dataItem.IFSCode);

    //var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataItem);
    //self.Currency(vm);
};

//Add
self.addCurrency = function () {
    self.isGridVisible(false);
    self.isAddVisible(true);
    self.isEditVisible(false);
    self.reset();
}

// Cancel Edit
self.cancelEdit = function () {
    self.isEditVisible(false);
    self.isGridVisible(true);
}

// Cancel Add
self.cancelAdd = function () {
    self.isAddVisible(false);
    self.isGridVisible(true);
}

//Reset 
self.reset = function () {
    self.ID(0);
    self.Id_Region("");
    self.Description("");
    self.Symbol("");
    self.PayPalCode("");
    self.IFSCode("");
}

//Actions --------------------------------------------------

var Currency = {
    ID: self.ID,
    Id_Region: self.Id_Region,
    Description: self.Description,
    Symbol: self.Symbol,
    PayPalCode: self.PayPalCode,
    IFSCode: self.IFSCode
};

//Create
self.createCurrency = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Currency/CreateCurrency",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(Currency),
        success: function (data) {
            self.isEditVisible(false);
            self.isAddVisible(false);
            self.isGridVisible(true);
            $("#gridCurrencies").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        }
    }).fail(
         function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
             alert(err);
         });
}


// Update
self.updateCurrency = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Currency/UpdateCurrency",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(Currency),
        success: function (data) {
            self.isEditVisible(false);
            self.isEditVisible(false);
            self.isGridVisible(true);
            $("#gridCurrencies").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        }
    })
}


//Delete
self.deleteCurrency = function (currency) {
    $.confirm({
        title: "Delete",
        content: "Sure to delete ?",
        confirm: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Currency/DeleteCurrency",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON(currency),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#gridCurrencies").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                }
            }).fail(
        function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            alert(err);
        });
        },
        cancel: function () {

        }
    });
}
};
```

---

in the view I call applybinding and then based on selected row of the Telerik  grid I call editCurrency or deleteCurrency.

```
<script>

var viewModel = null;

$(function () {
    viewModel = new currencyVm();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function deleteCurrency(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    viewModel.deleteCurrency(dataItem);
}

function editCurrency(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    viewModel.editCurrency(dataItem);
}

</script>
```

---

In the markup I have the html elements with the bindings:

Thi is the div for add:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="visible: isAddVisible" style="display:none">
    <div class="panel-heading">Add New Currency</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IFSCode)
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.IFSCode, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" class="form-control " />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PayPalCode)
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.PayPalCode, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" class="form-control " />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Symbol)
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.Symbol, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" class="form-control " />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.Description" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input data-bind="click: $root.createCurrency" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="@DbRes.T("Save", "Common")" />
                <input data-bind="click: cancelAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" value="@DbRes.T("Cancel", "Common")" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

the edit div is like the add div but use different binding like data-bind="value: IFSCode"

---

The problem is that in add mode it work but when I edit I dont see nothing
in the textbox elements.

Also I use the  to debug,
in add mode I can see the observables updating while I type something in textbox,
in edit mode the observables are emtpy and remain while typeing something.

May some body help please to understand what appen to this code
Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: You should show your editCurrency div since that's the one that isn't working. We need to see how editCurrency is being called and what is passed into it as parameters.

Comment: Are you using [Knockout-Kendo](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/knockout-js-and-kendo-ui---a-potent-duo)?

Comment: Thanks for answer I solved thanks again